# Converting mol files to InChiKey in large batches

Tags: software, cheminformatics

I want to convert `mol` files to `InChiKey`. I am using `OpenBabel` for the conversion but I have over `500` mol files and converting them one by one is too time consuming. Is there some way to convert them all at once?

**Edit 1** This is a sample mol file

```
0187.cdx
  Sample

  8  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -0.4125    0.7145    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.8250    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.4125   -0.7145    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.4125   -0.7145    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.8250    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.4125    0.7145    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.6500    0.0000    0.0000 Cl  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.6500    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  2  0      
  2  3  1  0      
  3  4  2  0      
  4  5  1  0      
  5  6  2  0      
  6  1  1  0      
  2  7  1  0      
  5  8  1  0      
M  END
```

Also I want to know is there some other format which can combine mol files into one.I think I had heard of another format like `mol` which can combine many mol files,but I cannot remember the name of that format

**Edit 2**-  What is `SDF` format? Can it combine many mol files into one?

Comment: Could you include the current scheme you are using? What operating system are you using? I am pretty sure there is a batch way to do things like that. (A small sample file would also be appreciated.)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I am using V2000 and OS is windows 8.I have editted my question.

Comment: Are you converting the files in a command line or do you use a gui program?

Comment: You can store several molecules in one mol file, but I believe you have to change to the newer standard.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I am using GUI of openbabel

Comment: @Martin-マーチン What is  `SDF` format.Wikipedia says it can wraps many mol files.Can it be used in my case?

Comment: I have no knowledge about mol files in general, not much knowledge about InChI other than that I read the FAQ. I cannot help you on this case, but I can try to make it easier for others to answer it for you. You can [edit] in all of the comments above, since they provide context to the question.

Comment: @LifeIsGood An SDF file is really just a bunch of MOL files one after the other. Doesn't the openbabel gui allow you to multi-select files? The alternative might be to open notepad and a command prompt and learn how to write batch files :)

Comment: If you have any sort of UNIX shell installed (such as Cygwin), I can give you a shell script that will do the trick (i.e., loop through your files and convert them) - is this an option for you?

Comment: Also, see this answer to a previous question : http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/9255/4665

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Ok I can install Cygwin

Comment: @gilleain I tried to write 2 mol files just after another but open babel converts just the first mol file in it.In `SDF` after `M END` of first mol file,should I start the next mol file immediately from the next line?

Comment: @LifeIsGood Sorry, I should have been clearer - there is a little more to the SDF format than just a series of mol files (there are spacer records IIRC). Probably best to do this with Cygwin and Todd's script.

Comment: @gilleain No,it worked for me.I added `$$$$` after `M  END` and then immediately after I started the next mol files.It worked.Thanks a lot

Comment: @ToddMinehardt I figured out a way.Thanks anyway

Comment: Good to hear. Just in case you or others want a handy one-liner:  `for i in $(ls *.mol); do name=${i%.mol}; babel -imol $i -oinchi $name.inchi; done`

Comment: @Todd Since the question is not worded as specific to an operating system, I would encourage you to post the one-liner as an answer, with the system you tested it on. If bash, `for i in *.mol; do ...` should also work ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly why I wrote Open Babel.

`obabel *.mol -oinchikey -m`

As long as you're not exceeding the number of command line arguments, you're done.

Comment: I should point out that since `babel` / `obabel` will process all the filenames internally, this is faster than approaches using the shell. **If** you have too many files in a  directory (e.g., me), you want something like `find . -name "*.mol" -print0 | xargs -0 -I % obabel % -oinchi -m`

Answer (score 1):

On a system where you're working in the bash shell, in your working directory where the .mol files reside, run this on the command line:

`for i in $(ls *.mol); do name=${i%.mol}; babel -imol $i -oinchi $name.inchi; done`

I have successfully tested this on machines running Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04.